# Rendering Textures in OpenGL ES 2.0 with VBO/IBO (IPhone)

Tags: iphone, textures, opengl-es-2.0

I'm trying to render a simple quad with a texture using a vertex buffer object and an index buffer object. I haven't seen any solutions for how to do this with an IBO using glDrawElements. In any case, all that appears to happen is that the quad is textured using only the upper left hand pixel of the texture image.

This is how initialize an entity that will be rendered:

```
void Entity::init(){

// create triangle verticies
numVerticies = 20;
verticies = new GLfloat[numVerticies];

// 3 verts, 2 tex coords
verticies[0] = -1.0f;  verticies[1] = -1.0f;  verticies[2] = 0.0f;  verticies[3] = 0.0f;  verticies[4] = 0.0f;
verticies[5] = 1.0f;   verticies[6] = 1.0f;   verticies[7] = 0.0f;  verticies[8] = 1.0f;   verticies[9] = 1.0f;
verticies[10] = -1.0f; verticies[11] = 1.0f;  verticies[12] = 0.0f; verticies[13] = 0.0f; verticies[14] = 1.0f;
verticies[15] = 1.0f;  verticies[16] = -1.0f; verticies[17] = 0.0f; verticies[18] = 1.0f;  verticies[19] = 0.0f;

// create face indicies
numIndicies = 6;
indicies = new GLushort[numIndicies];
indicies[0] = 0; indicies[1] = 1; indicies[2] = 2;
indicies[3] = 0; indicies[4] = 3; indicies[5] = 1;

// generate buffers for geometry
glGenBuffers(2, geometryBuffer);

// buffer the data to the vertex buffer
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, geometryBuffer[0]);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(verticies) * numVerticies, verticies, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

// buffer the data to the index buffer
glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, geometryBuffer[1]);
glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(indicies) * numIndicies, indicies, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

rotation = 0.0f;

// load a texure object
std::string path = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath] UTF8String];
path += "/test.png";
NSString *fileName = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:path.c_str()];

NSError *error;
GLKTextureInfo *texture = [GLKTextureLoader textureWithContentsOfFile:fileName options:nil error:&error];
if(error || texture == nil){
    NSLog(@"Error loading texture %@\n", error);
}

// get the texture id
tex = [texture name];
}
```

And this is how I render the object ( I should mention that I call glUseProgram before calling this method):

```
void Entity::render(GLint uniformPos, GLint uniformTex, GLKMatrix4 projection){

GLKMatrix4 modelViewProjection = GLKMatrix4Multiply(projection, modelView);

// bind and enable enable verticies
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, geometryBuffer[0]);  
glEnableVertexAttribArray(GLKVertexAttribPosition);
glVertexAttribPointer(GLKVertexAttribPosition, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 5 * sizeof(GLfloat), BUFFER_OFFSET(0));  

// enable tex coords
glEnableVertexAttribArray(GLKVertexAttribTexCoord0);
glVertexAttribPointer(GLKVertexAttribTexCoord0, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 5 * sizeof(GLfloat), BUFFER_OFFSET(12));

// bind the index buffer
glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, geometryBuffer[1]);

// bind the texture
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, tex);

// render with uniforms
glUniform1i(uniformTex, 0);
glUniformMatrix4fv(uniformPos, 1, 0, modelViewProjection.m);
glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, numIndicies, GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0);

// disable attributes and buffers
glDisableVertexAttribArray(GLKVertexAttribPosition);
glDisableVertexAttribArray(GLKVertexAttribTexCoord0);
glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
}
```

So I figured this out.

This:

```
// enable tex coords
glEnableVertexAttribArray(GLKVertexAttribTexCoord0);
glVertexAttribPointer(GLKVertexAttribTexCoord0, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 5 * sizeof(GLfloat), BUFFER_OFFSET(12));
```

Needs to be this:

```
GLint texCoordLoc = glGetAttributeLocation(program, texCoordAttributeName);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(texCoordLoc);
glVertexAttribPointer(texCoordLoc, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 5 * sizeof(GLfloat), BUFFER_OFFSET(12));
```

Comment: I've removed the answer you added to the question body because otherwise it looks like the question hasn't been answered. You are completely free to answer your own question (and well done on persevering) but please could you post it as an answer, then give it a tick? Your original edits are still available [here](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/8632573/3) or [here](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/8632573/revisions)